# regex re.sub replacing string with parts of itself

Tags: python, regex, replace

I need to replace parts of the names stored in a JSON file, for example replacing this:

```
"name":"S. tuberosum subsp. andigenum (ADG) 2-1-2-2"
```

with this:

```
"name":"S. tuberosum subsp. andigenum (ADG)"
```

i.e. I need to eliminate the numbers and hyphens following the name.

I am using `re.sub` but I can't figure out the right expressions, especially how to replace the string with a part of it.

I have tried this:

```
new_text = re.sub(r"(name.[:]..*)\s\d+-+", "name.[:]..*"  , initial_text)
```

Comment: Are there any other numbers with hyphens besides the ones you want to remove?

Comment: there are other numbers but they are without hyphens

Comment: I would start by reading the JSON file into a Python data structure first, so you don't have to deal with the `"name":` part in the regex, which only complicates things further.

Answer (score 1):

You need to match only the part you want to remove with `re.sub` and replace it by an empty string:

```
import re
string = '"name":"S. tuberosum subsp. andigenum (ADG) 2-1-2-2"'
print(re.sub('(\s(\d-)*\d)', '', string))
```

Output

```
"name":"S. tuberosum subsp. andigenum (ADG)"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

`re.sub("(\d+-\d+-*)", ""  , initial_text)`

this will replace 'number-number-(optional)' , hope it works

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import re
s = '"name":"S. tuberosum subsp. andigenum (ADG) 2-1-2-2"'
new_s = re.sub('(?<=[A-Z]\))\s[\d-]+', '', s)
```

Output:

```
'"name":"S. tuberosum subsp. andigenum (ADG)"'
```